# Message handler

Tags: java, server

The code bellow is code of "Hello" message handler. It works, but I really don't like as it looks.
The "hello" protocol contains three messages:

1. client -> server: diffie-hellman client public parameters
2. server -> client: diffie-hellman server public parameters
3. client -> server: used data

Could you please review the code. Any comments are welcome.

```
public class HelloHandler implements Runnable {

    final private static int MSG_TIMEOUT = 5000; // Response receive timeout in milliseconds

    final private static Server server = Server.getInstance();
    final private static Logger logger = server.getLogger();
    final private static ClientsRepository repository = server.getClientsRepository();

    final private static Map<SocketAddress, HelloHandler> handlers = new ConcurrentHashMap<SocketAddress, HelloHandler>();

    final private SocketAddress address;

    private DatagramPacket keyExchange = null;
    private DatagramPacket userData = null;
    private CipherPair ciphers;

    /*
     * Handles all hello messages
     * This method runs in context of the main thread (server)
     */
    public static void handle(DatagramPacket packet) {

        SocketAddress address = packet.getSocketAddress();
        byte type = PacketParser.getHeader(packet);

        if (type == DH_EXCH) {  //DH exchange starts

            if (handlers.containsKey(address) || repository.containsKey(address)) {
                logAndSend(REJECT, "Already active", address);
                return;
            }

            HelloHandler handler = new HelloHandler(packet);
            handlers.put(address, handler);
            server.getExecutor().execute(handler);
            return;
        }

        if (type == USER) { //user sent it's data

            HelloHandler handler = handlers.get(address);

            if (handler == null) {
                logAndSend(TIMEOUT, "Timeout", address);
                return;
            }

            handler.handleUser(packet);
        }

    }

    private HelloHandler(DatagramPacket packet) {
        keyExchange = packet;
        address = packet.getSocketAddress();
    }

    private void handleUser(DatagramPacket packet) {
        if (userData == null)
            userData = packet;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        DatagramPacket packet;

        try {

            packet = processKeyExchange();
            server.send(packet);

            keyExchange = null; // help GC

            packet = waitForPacket();

            if (!server.isRunning())
                return;

            if (packet == null) {
                logAndSend(TIMEOUT, "Timeout", address);
                return;
            }

            packet = processUserData();
            if (packet != null)
                server.send(packet);

            return;

        } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) { // we cannot be here
            logger.severe("Hello handler: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        } catch (IllegalMessageException e) {
            logAndSend(ILLEGAL_MSG, e.getMessage(), address);
            return;

        } finally {
            handlers.remove(address);
        }
    }

    private DatagramPacket waitForPacket() {
        
        // Use the simplest polling
        long timeOutTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + MSG_TIMEOUT;
        boolean timeOut = false;
        
        while (userData == null && !timeOut && server.isRunning()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {};
            
            timeOut = System.currentTimeMillis() >= timeOutTime;
        }
        
        return userData;
    }

    /*
     * Process first message (key exchange) sent by client
     * throws IllegalMessageException if we cannot get public key from message 
     */
    private DatagramPacket processKeyExchange() 
    throws NullPointerException, IOException, IllegalMessageException {

        try {
            Message<DHPublicKeyParams> message = PacketParser.parse(keyExchange, DHPublicKeyParams.class);
            DHPublicKeyParams clientKeyExchangeParams = message.getData();

            SecurityHelper security = SecurityHelper.getInstance();
            DHPublicKeyParams serverKeyExchangeParams = security.getPublicKeyParams();

            ciphers = security.finalizeAggreement(clientKeyExchangeParams);
            return PacketBuilder.build(DH_EXCH, serverKeyExchangeParams, address);

        } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new IllegalMessageException(e);
        }
    };

    /*
     * Currently it is a dummy method that shows that we can read encrypted data
     */
    private DatagramPacket processUserData() 
    throws NullPointerException, IOException, IllegalMessageException {

        Message<UserData> message = PacketParser.parse(userData, ciphers.getReadCipher(), UserData.class);

        System.out.println(message.getData().toString());
        repository.put(message.getData());

        return null;

    };

    /*
     * logs error and send response to client 
     */
    private static void logAndSend(byte type, String text, SocketAddress address) {
        logger.warning(buildMessage(text, address));
        server.send(PacketBuilder.build(type, text, address));
    };

    
    private static String buildMessage(String text, SocketAddress address) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Hello handler: ");
        sb.append(text);
        sb.append(" form: ");
        sb.append(Util.sockAddrToString(address));

        return sb.toString();

    }

}
```

Comment: Two things without reviewing the whole thing: StringBuilder only buys you something when using a loop or if you have an unknown number of parts. And `System.currentTimeMillis` is *wall-clock time*, meaning it observes time changes (leap seconds, daylight saving etc.). You either want an `Instant`, or `System.nanotime`.

Comment: @Bobby Thanks for the comments.  I will change the code.